# IBM Designer client launching Forms & Views into Notes Client! CLFRJ0010E sometimes

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

Hi XPages app developers.

Some weird stuff happening between the Notes Client and the Designer Client:

I launch Notes then right-click an app and tell it to **Open in Designer**.

I wait for it to load, it does, but funny, it says "IBM Notes in the title bar".   I proceed to select the **Xpages Perspective**;  I open the list of Views and select a view to Edit.

And BOOM!  it opens the view in a kind-of design mode in my regular Notes client!  Messed up or what?

Who's seen this and has a solution?  Please share your thoughts!

Comment: Which Fixpack ?

Comment: It was 9.0.1 FP10 SHF68.  I ended up uninstalling my clients, and re-installing SHF68 then ugraded to SHF252.   Everything's looking "normal" again (for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever it was, reinstalling worked.